# Program directory in Objective-C (OSX)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I'm developing an OSX-application and in it, I'd like to know what the current directory is (i.e. the directory which holds .app-file).

At the moment, I'm using the following code:

```
NSString *dir=[[NSFileManager defaultManager] currentDirectoryPath];
[[NSAlert alertWithMessageText:@"dir"
                 defaultButton:@"OK"
               alternateButton:nil
                   otherButton:nil
     informativeTextWithFormat:dir] runModal];
```

When running from Xcode (Run-button), this gives me the debug directory (which *is* what I'm looking for), but when double-clicking the app in Finder (so, in the debug directory), it's giving me `/` which puzzles me.

Why does this happen and how can I get the current directory reliably?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is the bundle folder:

```
NSString *appPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
```

([reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSBundle/bundlePath)).

Comment: Thanks, this was what I was looking for! (In fact, not _exactly_: I used `[[[NSBundle mainbundle] bundlePath] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent]` to get what I wanted :) )

Comment: @tomsmeding Ah yes, I missed the *holds* bit from " the directory which holds .app-file".

Answer (score 2):

When programming in Apple Swift you will get the application path with:

```
let pathtoapplication: String = NSBundle.mainBundle().bundlePath
```